# $(...).pickatime is not a function in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

i have a timepicker add but this TypeError: $(...).pickatime is not a function

```
$('.timepicker').pickatime({
   Default: 'now', // Set default time: 'now', '1:30AM', '16:30'
   fromnow: 0,       // set default time to * milliseconds from now (using with default = 'now')
   twelvehour: false, // Use AM/PM or 24-hour format
   donetext: 'OK', // text for done-button
   cleartext: 'Clear', // text for clear-button
   canceltext: 'Cancel', // Text for cancel-button
   autoclose: false, // automatic close timepicker
   ampmclickable: true, // make AM PM clickable
   aftershow: function(){} //Function for after opening timepicker
```

Comment: This is not an angular problem. Make sure you loaded scripts before using them. Check script ordering or you script loader settings.

Comment: include [pickatime](https://rawgit.com/amsul/pickadate.js/master/lib/picker.time.js) into your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add timepicker library in angular js

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
   Default: 'now', // Set default time: 'now', '1:30AM', '16:30'
   fromnow: 0,       // set default time to * milliseconds from now (using with default = 'now')
   twelvehour: false, // Use AM/PM or 24-hour format
   donetext: 'OK', // text for done-button
   cleartext: 'Clear', // text for clear-button
   canceltext: 'Cancel', // Text for cancel-button
   autoclose: false, // automatic close timepicker
   ampmclickable: true, // make AM PM clickable
   aftershow: function(){} //Function for after opening timepicker
```

https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/5467